# "Error ITMS-90168: “The binary you uploaded was invalid ..." in corona SDK Game

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, coronasdk, appstore-approval, corona-storyboard

I have developed a game in corona sdk, when i am uploading the ipa (binary) through application builder, i am facing "Error ITMS-90168: “The binary you uploaded was invalid ..."

Please help

Comment: Clean and build project and re-try to upload.

Comment: how to clean the project its developed in Corona SDK in lua language ?